# Apple iPhone Developer Program

Tags: iphone

How long does it usually take for individual developers to be accepted into the developer program?

I paid my pittance today and I'm feeling impatient.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I received my activation email after 16 hours. BUT when I tried to activate my account I got the following message: *We are unable to activate your Apple Developer Program membership*.

I sent apple an email but read on a lot of websites that they take up to 2 weeks to respond so I called them and they activated my account on the phone.

Comment: I'm from Brazil and had the same problem. Calling to Apple, they said that the problem was the accent of inputed city "São Paulo", system bug! they fixed and now there is no more "we are unable...." I'm in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was accepted the next day and it felt great. Still carrying a picture of me and that e-mail with me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

According to this link:
http://developer.apple.com/support/iphone/purchase-and-next-steps.html

> What happens after I purchase my program membership?
>
> Once you have completed your purchase, you will receive an order
>   acknowledgement email from the Apple Online Store. Within 24 hours,
>   you will receive an activation email from Apple Developer Support
>   providing detail on how to access your iOS Developer Program resources
>   and benefits to start developing your iOS apps.

It may take up to 24 hours. I got mine in around 20 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It should only take a day for an individual program.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes longer to get access to iTunes Connect, but access to the developer forums, etc. should be no more than a day.  I waited a week before I had iTunes Connect access.